# How to remove the characters "{" and "}" from string after reading it from file using TCL?

Tags: string, tcl

The string:

```
{ii= 10 } & {jj= 2 }
```

I need:

```
ii= 10 & jj= 2
```

I tried:
`string trim`, `string replace`, `lreplace`,
and they do not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have

```
set x "{ii= 10 } & {jj= 2 }"
```

you can do

```
string map {\{ {} \} {}} $x
# -> ii= 10  & jj= 2
```

I.e. replace a literal left and right brace with the empty string.

But your string actually looks a lot like the string representation of a list, with automatically inserted braces to preserve the whitespace. Working with it as a list, all you need to do is

```
join $x
# -> ii= 10  & jj= 2
```

Using `string trim` doesn't work since it only removes characters from the ends of the string:

```
string trim $x \{\}
# -> ii= 10 } & {jj= 2
```

The `string replace` command is just too much work in this case.

The `lreplace` command works on list elements, not characters in strings.

Documentation: [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lreplace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreplace.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: it seems like this: {ii = 10} & {jj = 2}
where the elements from the first list are  "ii" , "=" , "10"
and the second list "jj","=", "2"

Comment: @LeoLima: I see a list of three strings: "ii= 10 ", "&", and "jj= 2 ". The strings can of course be treated as lists, but the first and last strings aren't canonical Tcl lists, as indicated by the trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
% set x "{ii= 10 } & {jj= 2 }"
{ii= 10 } & {jj= 2 }
% regsub -all {\{|\}} $x ""
ii= 10  & jj= 2
```

Here, its just removing all curly braces and replacing with empty string - like its deleting them